# ¿Cómo represento un llave compuesta en el Modelo Relacional?

Tags: base-de-datos

¿Cómo debo (si se puede) representar un llave compuesta en el Modelo Relacional, si cada tabla solo puede tener un atributo cómo Primary Key?

¿Debo darle la propiedad de PK a los dos *(o más)* campos que necesito convertir en llave compuesta?

Comment: Kibō_B, es **muy importante revisar [ask]** para que realices tus preguntas en el sitio, estas sean bien recibidas y obtengas la ayuda deseada.

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes representada la tabla ahora mismo? (con o sin llave compuesta)

Comment: Sin llave compuesta. 

Por eso pregunto _si se puede representar una llave compuesta en el Modelo Relacional_, ya que si hablamos de código en mysql, le decimos `primary key(campo1, campo2)` y listo. Tenemos nuestra clave compuesta: cómo represento, _si se puede hacer_, esa referencia en el Modelo Relacional?. Se puede, se debe? o sólo debería implementarlo en código, y ya?

Comment: ¿Entonces quieres saber cómo se representaría en un diagrama entidad-relación? ¿O estamos hablando de algún programa en concreto que luego generará el código? La respuesta sería diferente en esos dos casos (y casi parece que quieres lo segundo)

Comment: Si, eso es, pero sería en el Modelo Relacional. Se puede representar en un Modelo Relacional? Entonces si se puede en un ER, cómo se haría. Y dando respuesta a la segunda pregunta no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una tabla puede tener más de un atributo como clave primaria. En esos casos, cada uno de los atributos que forman la clave primaria se mostrarán en el diagrama de la misma forma que se haría una clave primaria individual.

Por ejemplo, dependiendo del tipo de diagrama que estés utilizando, harías como indicas en la propia pregunta dándole la propiedad [PK] a todos los atributos que formen la clave:

[image: Modelo Entidad-Relación con dos claves]

O subrayando los atributos que formen la clave:

[image: Diagrama Entidad-Relación con dos claves]

Comment: Excelente! Muchas gracias por la colaboración y disculpas las molestias causadas.